# Problems with my printer!

Tags: 22.04, printing, canon

I had a MF6160dw printer and I need to restart everyday cups with "systemctl restart cups" to connect my printer with my PC. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. I'm very frustrated! I can't resolve this issue. Thanks in advance  for your help!

Update

systemctl status cups

```
● cups.service - CUPS Scheduler
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cups.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-10-23 10:57:23 CST; 10min ago
TriggeredBy: ● cups.socket
             ● cups.path
       Docs: man:cupsd(8)
       Main PID: 1290 (cupsd)
       Status: "Scheduler is running..."
       Tasks: 13 (limit: 153459)
       Memory: 48.3M
       CPU: 614ms
       CGroup: /system.slice/cups.service
               ├─1290 /usr/sbin/cupsd -l
               ├─2338 cnijbe2
               ├─2343 cnijlgmon3
               ├─5987 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus:// ""
               ├─5988 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus:// ""
               ├─5989 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus:// ""
               ├─5992 Canon-MF6100-Series-UFRII-LT 58 israel 01-Registro_OPES_JIMJ.pdf 1 "PageSize=Le>
               ├─5993 "usb://Canon/MF6100%20Series?serial=180CACdb2556&interface=1" 58 israel 01-Regi>
               ├─5994 /usr/bin/cnrsdrvufr2 5 7 "PageSize=Letter OutputBin=Auto BindEdge=Left CNImageR>
               └─5999 /usr/bin/cnpkmoduleufr2r --format=2 --output=1 --cmd_fd=6 --res_fd=12 --dat_fd=>
```

oct 23 14:55:19 israel-MS-7D67 systemd[1]: Starting CUPS Scheduler...
lines 1-23

Comment: Please do `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt upgrade cups` and let us know if it works.

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 cupsd`. Read `man journalctl `.

Comment: Hi @Raffles . I did both commands, but nothing change!

Comment: Hi @waltinator . The computer is conected by USB to my PC. The command that you recommended me did not work. The output was: Failed to add match 'cupsd': argument invalid

Comment: Can you access this file `/var/log/cups/error_log` and depending on the size, paste into your question or use pastebin?

Comment: Sorry, my typo, `cups` not `cupsd`. Or try the device name `/dev/lp`

Comment: Hi @Raffles  The file is here (https://pastebin.com/8N0ik3sH).

Comment: When CUPS is locked out, what does `systemctl status cups` return? Edit the output into your question.

Comment: Does your printer have a sleep function? Can you check this in the printer manual? My internet connection is bad at the moment and I will be out all day tomorrow, will look again on Wednesday. So please check to see if it is the printer itself going to sleep. I don't think you have a problem with CUPS. I often have to restart my printer, which is also a Canon. Canon Linux support is poor. You can also try settings for your printer by going to URL `http://127.0.0.1:631/admin` in a browser.